# how to start a sharepoint 2013 reusable workflow automatically on publish

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow2013, reusable-workflow

I have created a reusable workflow using SharePoint 2013 workflow template in SharePoint designer 2013.

When i published it and associated it with a library, the option " start a workflow on item publish" is grayed out.

Any solution?

Also, when i thought to start the workflow manually on a publish button in context menu, i am not able to see the workflow because as per the requirement, the user should have read permission on site. So i could give user contribute permission on only on the library.

So how do i get the functionality to start the workflow for content approval on item publish(either automatically or manually )